# Harmonic oscillator ensemble

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Suppose we have an ensemble of classical 1D harmonic  oscillators, with displacement $x = A \cos(\omega t+\phi)$, where the phase angle $\phi$ is equally likely to be any angle between $0$ and $2 \pi$.

My problem is to find the probability $P(x)dx$ that $x$ lies between $x$ and $x+dx$, for a fixed time $t$.

So I started by figuring that the probability for phi to lie in a certain range is $d\phi(2 \pi)^{-1}$. Then I proceeded to integrate this for all values of $\phi$ such that $x$ lies between $x$ and $x+dx$. But my result is not making sense. Is this the wrong approach?

Thanks

Comment: Might help: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/76235/ensemble-of-harmonic-oscillators  and I would use mathjax in your post, it's simple to use and gives you a much better chance of an answer, best of luck

Comment: Are you trying to solve for a single oscillating point with many harmonic terms, or a sequence of connected 1-D oscillators?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, given that they have $x = A\cos{(\omega t + \phi)}$ it sounds like they must be uncoupled oscillators (i.e. this is a classical analogue of the Einstein model of a solid).

Comment: Is the ensemble in contact with a heat bath?  i.e. are you supposed to use the Boltzmann distribution?  Otherwise, does the system lie in some range of energy from $E$ to $E + dE$, in which case you have to use other methods?

Comment: I figured it out, I'll post the answer when I have time

Comment: Paul, you're supposed to write "I have a proof  but the margin of this web page is too small for me to write it" :-)